# RunProject on Ubuntu Server

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, nginx

I'm trying to run a service that starts an Asp.net project on my linux server.

my project files are available at `/www/wwwroot/ioi.kimiamana.ir`
and my dll is at `/www/wwwroot/ioi.kimiamana.ir/SinaMN75.dll`

I can Start the project by simply run `dotnet SinaMN75.dll` and its working fine. but but the service I wrote is not running.
here is my Service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Example .NET Web API App running on Linux

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/www/wwwroot/ioi.kimiamana.ir
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /www/wwwroot/ioi.kimiamana.ir/SinaMN75Api.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

but after running

```
sudo systemctl enable kimiamana.service
sudo systemctl start kimiamana.service
sudo systemctl status kimiamana.service
```

I'm getting this error:

```
● kimiamana.service - Example .NET Web API App running on Linux
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kimiamana.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-10-04 20:28:45 UTC; 2s ago
    Process: 156694 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /www/wwwroot/ioi.kimiamana.irSinaMN75Api.dll (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

I'm using dotnet 8, ubuntu 20, and nginx

Comment: Do you get anything else in the output of the `sudo systemctl status kimiamana.service`?

Comment: no I copied everything

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have said about the location of your files, I think you want this in your `ExecStart`:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /www/wwwroot/ioi.kimiamana.ir/SinaMN75Api.dll
```